# How to makes height auto for React Bootstrap forms

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a form using React-bootstrap

```
 <Form.Group controlId="exampleForm.ControlSelect2">
    <Form.Label>Example multiple select</Form.Label>
    <Form.Control as="select" multiple>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
    </Form.Control>
  </Form.Group>
```

And this is how it looks like. this is just a vanilla example taken from the React-Bootstrap doc:

[image: This is how it looks like]

I'd like to change the height of the form so it is high enough that no scroll will be needed. I tried applying an override in my css file

```
.form-control {
  height: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

But nothing happens. How to do it? Thanks!

Comment: `overflow-y: auto;` should be `overflow-y: hidden;` according to the CSS [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-y.asp)

Comment: @Tangy Thanks. But that only hides the scroll, my trouble is with the height.

Comment: Ah I see, is the Form a child of another element? Usually, the parent element controls how much height the child has and that could be forcing the scroll bar to appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you correctly follow the guidelines [Doc. react Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/forms/) ?

This for `select`

```html
<Form.Group controlId="exampleForm.ControlSelect1">
    <Form.Label>Example select</Form.Label>
    <Form.Control as="select">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
    </Form.Control>
  </Form.Group>
```

and this for `multiple select`

```html
<Form.Group controlId="exampleForm.ControlSelect2">
    <Form.Label>Example multiple select</Form.Label>
    <Form.Control as="select" multiple>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
    </Form.Control>
  </Form.Group>
```

Comment: Thanks for catching that i copied the wrong snippet. Still, the question is how to adjust the height of the form? Thanks.

Comment: If you want to make all option visible, may be you can modify 
`<Form.Control as="select" htmlSize={5} custom>`

More details: [custom form](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/forms/#forms-custom-select)